# Taking HTML output and translating to python

Tags: python, html, flask

I am using flask to create a website. I want to take an input from a slider and then depending on the output from the slider send the website user to a different page. For example if they input 10 into the slider send them to a page specifically designed for 10.

Here is my python code:

```
#imports flask
from flask import Flask
#Imports templates so we can use html
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from markupsafe import escape

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def test():
    return render_template('main.html')

@app.route("/slider/")
def Slider():
    return "<p>Slideeeeeeeeeeeee!</p>"

@app.route('/user/<output>')
def show_user_profile(output):
    # show the user profile for that user
    return f'User {escape(output)}'
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {background-color: rgb(184, 251, 159);}
body {font-family: 'Century Gothic', monospace;}
h1   {color: rgb(0, 0, 0);}
h1 {font-family: 'Century Gothic', monospace;}
p    {color: rgb(0, 0, 0);}
p {font-family: 'Century Gothic', monospace;}
form    {color: rgb(0, 0, 0);}
form {font-family: 'Century Gothic', monospace;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Sprout</h1>

<!--Slider--> 
<div class="slider">
<input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" oninput="output.innerText = this.value">
<p id="output">5</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The slider part in the HTML is the slider.

I tried just directly calling the output variable in python because they are in the same folder but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Dear below is the solution to your problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
    body {
        background-color: rgb(184, 251, 159);
    }
    body {
        font-family: 'Century Gothic', monospace;
    }
    h1 {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    h1 {
        font-family: 'Century Gothic', monospace;
    }
    p {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    p {
        font-family: 'Century Gothic', monospace;
    }
    form {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    form {
        font-family: 'Century Gothic', monospace;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sprout</h1>
<form method="POST" target="_blank" action="" id="setPageForm" name="setPageForm">
        <input type="range" id="set_page" min="0" max="10" value="5" step="1" name="set_page_value"
            oninput="output.innerHTML=this.value" onchange="setPage(); this.form.submit();">
</form>
<p class="value1" id="output">5</p>
<script>
    function setPage() {
        var element = document.getElementById('set_page');
        var newValue = document.getElementById('set_page').value;
        document.forms.setPageForm.action = '/slider/' + newValue;
    }
</script>
```

And as far the Flask part is concerned, you have to add number in the path for which you want the page to be displayed as shown below:

```
@app.route("/slider/2")
def Slider_2():
    return "<p>Slideeeeeeeeeeeee!</p>"

@app.route("/slider/3")
def Slider_3():
    return "<p>Slideeeeeeeeeeeee!</p>"

@app.route("/slider/4")
def Slider_4():
    return "<p>Slideeeeeeeeeeeee!</p>"
```

and so on.

No doubt there will be better solutions then this approach but this will give you an idea for beginning with Flask.